# JavaScript as a first programming language?

Tags: javascript, programming-languages

I would like to learn how to program, starting from scratch. I've come across an online beginner's course based on JavaScript which seems to be very well-done. However, a friend of mine counseled me against taking this course, arguing that I should rather start with Visual Basic or C#. His rationale is that JavaScript apparently doesn’t force you to adhere to high standards of programming best practices (it lets you get away with too much), and it might thus lead a beginner to develop bad programming habits. Do you agree? Is this really that big of an issue? Can't you start with JavaScript and later add a lower-level language that requires more rigor? Thanks in advance for the advice!

Comment: It depends.....What do you want to do with this language once you have learnt it?

Comment: Not recommended. Your friend is fully right.

Comment: Read: http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-as-a-first-language/

Comment: @Mitch: I have a business background and plan to launch an Internet startup. I'd love to be able to help actually build the product.

Answer (score 9):

JavaScript is my favorite programming language in the world, but it's probably one of the **worst** programming languages to start learning with.  There are hidden nuances around every corner.  For example functions can be called in *four* different ways (the last two are grouped together), each of which affects what `this` will be equal to

```
 foo();                     //this = global object or undefined in strict mode
 obj.foo();                 //this = obj
 new Foo();                 //this = object inheriting from Foo's prototype
 foo.call(lala, 12, 3);
 foo.apply(lala, [12, 3]);  //this = lala
```

Then there's the fact that, though it doesn't support classes, it really wants developers to think that it does:

```
var p = new Person(); //Person's a class, right?
```

And when it comes time to create objects, you have oh so many options to choose from:

```
function Person(name){
    this.name = name;
}
var p = new Person("Adam");
```

---

```
var p = { name: "Adam" };
```

---

```
function createPerson(name){
    var that = {};
    that.name = name;
    return that;
}
var p = createPerson("Adam");
```

And of course inheritance will be completely different depending on which of the above you choose.

Combine all that with function scope, no compiler to point out obvious errors, semicolon-insertion to **create** errors for you, and I'd strongly suggest you start with a more traditional language like C# or Java.

Comment: Well, Ruby has seven different syntaxes for lambda, and it's my favourite language :-)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - JS is **my** favorite language; I love it.  I'm just saying it's not a good teaching language.

Comment: Doesn't all the above make it a good language to begin programming with?

Comment: @RobG - from my view, I'd see new developers getting lost in all the above.  But maybe I'm just biased having started with C++.

Comment: It probably depends on how it is taught. Most seem to just pick it up from surfing the web rather than formal training, which is probably why the skill level varies so much (and there are so many bad javascript coders).

Comment: aside from doing onMouseXXXXX() programming on HTML elements, Javascript is a bloody hard language for a newbie. It is too loose, so newbies should learn a strong OO language like Java before being given the riegns.

Answer (score 3):

This is a pretty subjective question, and as such depends what you end goal is. If you want to be a JavaScript programmer then learning JavaScript is correct. If you want to be a Windows App programmer then its not so relevant.

In general I would second that opinion however... I would learn a *real* programming language first. I would also try and find an application that is actually useful to you, whether it be a website or windows app. If you have a real use for the end result you'll be far more motivated, and consequently will learn a lot better. You'll also be thinking about the usability issues since you will really want to use it. When you do something just as an exercise you may not try as hard.

Comment: Javascript *is* a "real programming language".  One that, uncoincidentally, avoids a lot of the CRAP in languages like C++.

Comment: Hee hee - knew that would raise a bite.

Answer (score 2):

> There are a lot more ways to write terrible JavaScript than there are
>   ways to write terrible VB.NET, for example.

Yup - and there are a LOT more ways to write C++ that are *SO* terrible you don't even *REALIZE* your code is a ticking time bomb.

If there's ANY "worst choice for a first language", personally, my vote goes to C++. Hands down as "worst language for any beginner".  Because there's so much you have to learn before you can even do *simple* things with any degree of safety.

If you're interested in developing web applications, mobile applications, dynamic web pages or just about anything having to do with web design or development, knowing Javascript is indispensible.

For that reason alone, I think Javascript isn't only an ACCEPTABLE "first language", it can arguably be an IDEAL first language.

Additionally, Javascript is an extremely powerful, extremely interesting language in and of itself.

I would strongly urge you to get a copy of this short book:

- Javascript: The Good Parts, David Crockford

It won't teach you how to write Javascript (any number of web tutorials can help you with that).  But it *will* help put Javascript in a completely different perspective for you.

IMHO...

PS:
If I had to give a "best first language", I'd have to say Java.  Runners up: Python or Ruby.

Comment: I don't disagree with you about C++, but the question mentioned C# which would be a lot safer...

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript and Visual Basic both *seem* easy to beginners, and thus beginners often come to believe that they can teach themselves *without any guides or references*, and thus they pick up all sorts of bad habits while remaining completely unaware of various relatively basic programming concepts.

In your case that should not be a problem because you're already thinking about learning and following good programming practices. You've already identified a JS course that you intend to follow seriously (assuming you go with JS). You know about Stack Overflow so you can get help with specific problems as you go. On that basis I think it is reasonable for you to start with JavaScript.

(Having said that, Java or C# would be good choices too.)

I suggest you post the URL for the course you've identified: you might get some opinions about that course or some additional course suggestions. For a free online course this one seems pretty good: http://eloquentjavascript.net/ (I say "seems" because I have only read bits of it.)

If you do go ahead with JavaScript, please look into using http://jshint.com or http://jslint.com - both tools are designed to check your code and enforce some good practices (by complaining when you don't).

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful response. The course is offered by the Codecademy, which is, I believe, a young startup that offers programming courses. They offer the "Code Year", for people whose New Year's resolution is to learn how to code. See http://codeyear.com/. I've stumbled upon it on a VC blog: http://www.avc.com/a_vc/2012/01/learn-to-code-in-the-new-year.html.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's what I started with personally, and I think I write pretty good Visual Basic .NET. JavaScript's loose standards aren't really "loose" - they're just another way of thinking. You'll most likely find it more convenient, but it won't teach you to do things the wrong way; "stricter" languages will force you to adhere to the standards, so you can't write bad code in that sense just because you started out in JavaScript.

That said, though, it's true that there are a lot more ways to write *terrible* JavaScript than there are ways to write terrible VB.NET, for example. So be careful which tutorial you follow. People on Stack Overflow will generally point you in the right direction in terms of coding standards, too :)

Answer (score 1):

(*disclaimer: this post contains personal opinions and trolling attempts*)

[Edsger Dijkstra](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Edsger_W._Dijkstra) once said:

> It is practically impossible to teach good programming to students that have had a prior exposure to BASIC: as potential programmers they are mentally mutilated beyond hope of regeneration.

I think, this is still true for Visual Basic, only the consequences are more severe :-)

While my first language was C++, I think I would be a better programmer, if it were a dynamic language (Ruby, Lisp, Python or similar). Sure, they put less restrictions on you, but allow for greater possibilities and cleaner code!

When I recall how I had to iterate collections back then, having to create numerous single-serving functors, I become really happy that now I don't have to do this again :-)

#### Now, the serious part

I recommend starting with Ruby. It combines "classic" OOP and power of a dynamic language, with lots of features from functional languages. It is also very universal: you can write web apps, desktop apps and command line utils with this. Tons of libraries, etc.

I heard Python is good too.

Comment: Q: I think you're suggesting that learning Javascript can be an *excellent* first language, precisely *because* it's so dynamic.  If so, I wholeheartedly agree!

Comment: Visual Basic or Visual Basic .NET? (If you say .NET, I will -1 this `;)`)

Comment: @paulsm4: I would recommend Ruby over Javascript :-)

Comment: @minitech: no offense, man :-)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with your friend. If you really want to be a good programmer in the future i would suggest languages like Python or Java to begin with. The latest version of Python makes use of best practices.